# Reverting changes by hand

Tags: git, egit, tortoisegit

I'm using TortoiseGit and/or Eclipse's EGit.

Suppose I modify a file. The icon overlay changes to modified. I then change my mind and edit the file back to it's previous state. The icon overlay stays as modified.

As I was writing this question, after a couple minutes the icons got back to normal.

Is this how Git is supposed to work? Why?

I'm used to TortoiseSVN, which is smart enough to notice a file is back to it's original state right away.

Comment: This is a problem with the git client(s) you are using. This is not how "*git is supposed to work*"

Comment: I realize you are right, it's not about git at all, but about Git GUI clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I would guess that's just some delay before TortoiseGit and/or Eclipse's EGit notices the change. Issue the command `git status` from your terminal and you will have the correct results immediately.